# Hosting HTTPS over local network

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, progressive-web-apps

I am currently trying to develop a PWA, however, I can't work out how to get it hosted over the local network? It works fine when connecting to localhost from the host machine but will not connect from any other devices on the local network. I believe it might be to do with the fact that the PWA is served over HTTPS and I have tried setting up Open SSL but I'm not too sure whether this is actually the correct idea to get it served over the local network? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Https has nothing to do with it. Make sure whatever you're using to run the server is binding all on devices, not just the loopback device.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED my server looks like this: `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 6060, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});


//Redirect HTTP to HTTPS,
app.use(redirectToHTTPS([/localhost:(\d{4})/], [], 301));
//Handle requests for static files
app.use(require('express').static('public'));` And if I try to connect over the network I get "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

Comment: That has nothing to do with local networks. Other machines are reaching your server fine. Is your server set up for HTTPS? It's not magic, you need to set up keys and listen on the correct ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly use two options:

a) [Chrome Remote Debugging + Port Forwarding](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging): This will allow you to port forward your website to your mobile device

b) [Netlify Dev](https://docs.netlify.com/cli/get-started/#netlify-dev): This will give you a temporary URL with https you can use to access from mobile device

Comment: That's great, thank you for the response. I was unaware of the chrome port forwarding feature, very helpful thanks a lot, is there a way to achieve this wirelessly, or will it only work while the device is tethered? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Look into wireless ADB

Comment: “Quick Tip: Lose the cables, use Wireless ADB!” by Kaustav Jaiswal https://link.medium.com/ZTmwj16C36